# Autowire Bean again or use getter?

Tags: java, spring

I have an abstract class, which autowires some beans, for example a repository:

```
public abstract class A {
    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;

    protected void useRepository() {
        aRepository.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This abstract class uses that repository for some method. Now I also have a child class, which extends class `A` and also has a method, which uses `ARepository`.

```
public class B extends A {

    private void useRepositoryAgain() {
        aRepository.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Now my question:

How I see it there are two ways to do this:

1: Autowire the repository in class `B` again:

```
public class B extends A {
    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;
    ...
}
```

2: Create a getter method in class A:

```
public abstract class A {
    ...
    public ARepository getARepository() {
        return this.aRepository;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    private void useRepositoryAgain() {
        getARepository().doSomething();
    }
}
```

In my understanding, there shouldn't be a difference between the two, as autowiring the repository again would just return the same instance of it.

Is my understanding correct, or is there some significant difference between the two approaches which I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autowiring the bean again will not work. It will cause the member variable `aRepository` in class `A` to be `null`. Spring will only autowire the member variable in class `B` and not in `A`.

Instead, autowire it only in class `A` and not in class `B`, and make it `protected` instead of `private` in class `A` so that methods in the subclass `B` can also access it:

```
public abstract class A {
    @Autowired
    protected ARepository aRepository;

    protected void useRepository() {
        aRepository.doSomething();
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    private void useRepositoryAgain() {
        // Fine, since aRepository is protected in the superclass
        aRepository.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Is there a reason you suggest this approach, instead of making the field private and creating a getter? I thought this was the prefered way to do it.

Comment: @Niby you could also make it `private` and add a `protected` getter method, I think that's more a matter of personal preference / style. I don't like to add an unnecessary getter method myself.